# Kendo Grid filtering with an enumeration

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My model contains an enumeration that I'd like to filter the grid on when it's loaded via AJAX.

.cshtml Code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(x => x.Type);
            columns.Bound(x => x.Status); @*This is my enum*@
        })
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(ds => ds
                        .Ajax()
                        .ServerOperation(true)
                        .Filter(filter => filter.Add(x => x.Status).IsEqualTo(MyEnum.Updated))
                        .Read(read => read.Action("QueryAlerts", "Alert"))))
```

The filter request on the AJAX POST is going across as `Status~eq~'updated'` and returns an `Input string was not in a correct format` error.

I removed the filtering on the data source and used the filtering controls to see how that request is normally passed which looks like this: `Status~eq~2`.

I've tried casting the filter values to integers (e.g. `filter.Add(x => (int)x.Status).IsEqualTo((int)MyEnum.Updated)`) and that results in an invalid cast error to Int32 from the model which is expected by the Add method.

Can this problem be solved using Razor or is this a JavaScript fix?

Answer (score 0):

What data type is your x.Status? If it's an int then you don't need to cast it, only the enumeration:

```
filter.Add(x => x.Status).IsEqualTo((int)MyEnum.Updated)
```